# Opening a diffrent Macro-Enabled workbook from VBA code, security issues

Tags: vba, security, excel

So, I have a program I am writing (in the parent workbook).  In the program I need to open an .xlsm file (child),although I do not need to run the macros immediately.  My problem is that the way my security setting work means that when I try I get a pop-up shown in (http://www.sigmaxl.com/images/HelpDesk/sw1.jpg).

I am using the basic Workbooks.Open method, and I have 
Application.DisplayAlerts = False.  Is there any way I can disable the security message from the code in the parent workbook?  I am not allowed to change security settings.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately for your problem, there isn't a way to change the macro security settings from vba.  If you could place the child book in a location that Excel considers safe, then you could open & run it.

Comment: Is there a way to a way to automatically disable macros when opening (only when being opened from the parent code and not normally?)